# Errors: expected expression and expression result unused

Tags: c++, c++11

I have written a code that prompts the user to input a number and then tell them if it is odd or even. But it is giving me these errors that don't make sense at all. 
How do you fix them?

[image]

Comment: Every time someone posts a picture of code a kitten dies. The only thing worse than posting code pictures is posting links to code pictures. Please properly format and post your code as *text*. And btw, ... `std::cout << x << " is even\n";`

Comment: Posting pictures of code is superior for reading.

Comment: @YolandaHui Except if you have bad sight and need to use a screen reader. Or need to copy-paste a part of the text. Or need to search the text. Please read http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @YolandaHui Posting pictures of codes is **inferior** for *searching*. Picture uploads are meant for addressing visual needs that *require* it (ex: someone has a question about why their OpenGL code seems to be generating the wrong figure. Or... someone has a whiteboard snapshot of a data structure their prof described and they can't make heads nor tails of it). It's not for making colorful code posts.

Comment: No one should be searching my code.

Comment: @YolandaHui You think a question you ask here is meant to only *ever* help *you* ??? That's not what this site is about.

Comment: Remember that this forum is not only to help you right here and now, it's also for other future programmers with the same or a similar problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haven't used C++ in a while but i think it should look something like this

```cpp
if(x%2 == 0) 
{
  std::cout << x << "is even\n";
} 
else 
{
  std::cout << x << "is odd\n";
}
```

your errors are because you were basically saying

```cpp
cout << x;
"is even";
```

which doesn't make sense to the compiler or to anyone what exactly is supposed to happen with "is even"

Answer (score 1):

You should use `cout << x << "is_even"` instead of `cout << x; "is_even";`.

You get the warning about `expression result unused` because in your case you don't use `"is even"`.

And the error is because after your `if` without `{}` brackets there are 2 expressions.
You can omit brackets and use `else` after `if` only if there is one expression after `if`.

Try adding `{}` around the code after `if` and you will get only warnings about `expression result unused`.